# Why does my explore.exe and System make connections to my ISP?

Tags: windows, http, isp

I've noticed that the System process and explorer.exe make connections to my ISP at various times, whether I am using the web or if my computer is idle.

I see under Network Activity that the connection is made on remote port 80, so I imagine this is using the http protocol? Am I correct in saying this?

My question is, even though my browser is off, how and why would my System and explorer process connect to my ISP?

Comment: Explorer may manage time, which would mean it will hit NTP servers to check if the time is in sync periodically.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely source of those connections would be the Windows Update service, which periodically polls Microsoft servers in order to check for updates; various other system components could also use HTTP/HTTPS to connect to Microsoft and/or other Internet services.

This has nothing to do with web browsing: most Internet services today are provided as "web services", i.e. are based on the HTTP protocol but actually use it to send and receive data, not web pages.

If you are really curious, you can use tools such as [TCPView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/tcpview.aspx) to check the details of what connections are being made, from which processes and to which destinations.

Comment: I see that the processes being used are explorer.exe and System. Sometimes they will connect to a Microsoft server, but at other times I see those same processes connecting to my ISP (IP addresses that belong to them) on port 80.